# C# Console Application - I want it to recognize if a certain key is pressed

Tags: c#

C# Console Application - I want it to recognize if a certain key is pressed

This is my first year at high school (10th grade), and I've been learning c# for about a couple of months. I don't know much, but we've recently learned the "if" function, and I was wondering if there's any way (inside a console application, not a windows form) to make a certain key to do something. Please try to make it simple for me because I still don't know much. I think it has something to do with bools (we've learned about bools as well).

Comment: Do you know how to allow the user to input in the console and compute the value?

Comment: This is kind of a general question. What specifically are you seeking to do? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following method

```
ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
     // do something when Esc button has pressed
}
else if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
{
     // do something else when Space button has pressed
}
```

this method will not return until you press some key from the keyboard.
after that, you could check the key which pressed.

Comment: And how can i check which key was pressed?

Comment: @ItayHabani I will update my answer for you

Comment: @ItayHabani I updated my answer for you , if you have any other question I please let me know

Comment: @HakamFostok Ok, thank you so much :D

Comment: if this solve your problem, please mark this answer as accepted answer. this could be helpful for others also